# Regex to check date

Tags: python, regex

Hi i have written regex to check where ther string have the char like - or . or / or : or AM or PM or space .The follworig regex work for that but i want to make case fail if the string contain the char other than AMP .
import re

```
Datere = re.compile("[-./\:?AMP ]+")

FD = { 'Date' : lambda date : bool(re.search(Datere,date)),}

def Validate(date):

    for k,v in date.iteritems():
        print k,v
        print FD.get(k)(v)
```

Output:

```
Validate({'Date':'12/12/2010'})
Date 12/12/2010
True
Validate({'Date':'12/12/2010 12:30 AM'})
Date 12/12/2010
True

Validate({'Date':'12/12/2010 ZZ'})
Date 12/12/2010
True  (Expecting False)
```

Edited:
    Validate({'Date':'12122010'})
    Date 12122010
    False  (Expecting False)

How could i find the string have other than the char APM any suggestion.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you asking how to capture the date string, excluding 'AM', 'PM'?

Comment: @möter In short just making assumption the string is date based on the -or/or:orAMP or space char present in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
^[-./\:?AMP \d]*$
```

The changes to your regex are

- It's anchored with ^ and $ which means that the whole line should match and not partially
- the \d is added to the character class to allow digits

Now the regex basically reads as list of symbols that are allowed on 1 lines

If you want the empty string not to match then change the * to a +

Comment: +1 Thanks @buckely the regex work for perfect to caught the char other than AMP but if we provide the Validate({'Date':'12122010'}) it should fail

Comment: Why should it fail? I could read the date 1212-20-10 as Year 1212 day 20 month 10 which is valid. Agreed that yyyyddmm is a strange format but are you now saying that we should not only check the form but also check that the contents is a valid date? Then the question becomes what formats are you wanting to support.

Comment: @möter validating the syntax or validating the meaning? Although regexes van be used to distinguish existing dates from non existing it's not always pretty. Regexes are mostly used to validate syntax but maybe the OP thought they were more versatile

Answer (score 1):

You could use an expression like this instead:

```
^[-0-9./:AMP ]+$
```

`^` and `$` anchor the expression at the beginning and end of string, making sure there is nothing else in it (except an optional new line after `$`).

Comment: A "valid" date string under this regex would be: '-30/A-MP/2012/12'.

Comment: +1 @Thanks Qtax the regex work for perfect to caught the char other than AMP but if we provide the Validate({'Date':'12122010'}) it should fail – Shashi

Comment: @möter, yeah, even `:::`, but noone ever said that this expression tries to validate dates. (;

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious considering the code of the OP. And the title.

Answer (score 1):

The way you approach this is too naive to deal with garbled input like  '-30/A-MP/2012/12',  '-30/A-MP/20PA12/12'.

If you want to validate your dates robustly, how about:

```
import datetime
date = '12-12-2012 10:45 AM'
formats = ("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M %p", "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p", ...)
for fmt in formats:
    try:
        valid_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, fmt)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

You would have to define all possible formats, but you will get full datetime objects (or time or date objects, they work similar), and you can be absolutely sure they are valid. For a full explanation of the available format specifiers: http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime

Answer (score 1):

Kind of elaborate, but does the trick.

```
import re
Datere = re.compile("""
    ^(?:\d\d[-./\:]){2} ## dd_SEP_dd
    \d{4}\s* ## year may be followed by  spaces
    (?:\d\d[-./\:]\d\d\s+(?:AM|PM))? ## hh_SEP_mm spaces followed by AM/PM and this is optional
    \s*$""",re.X)

FD = { 'Date' : lambda date : bool(re.search(Datere,date)),}

def Validate(date):

    for k,v in date.iteritems():
        print k,v
        print FD.get(k)(v)

print Validate({'Date':'12/12/2010'})
print Validate({'Date':'12/12/2010 12:30 AM'})
print  Validate({'Date':'12/12/2010 ZZ'})
```

Comment: Under this regex, 12-20/2011 would be valid and 2012-20-12 would not be.

Comment: @möter, from OP examples its clear the his/her date(s) won't be swapping day/month/year places. so your second sample is a no issuer. for the first one we can capture separator then using it in validation regex if OP feels that as an issue.